# Exit confirm function and removing the function on submit with javascript and jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, forms

I want to be able to allow the user to confirm if they want to leave the page if they don't want to submit the form. 
However, I DONT want this function to work on the submit button. When the user clicks submit, I don't want them to be confused with an exit confirmation.
The id concerned is #publishbtn and I'm trying to use the .off method.
**The script is on the bottom of the page**
Not sure if this is an issue.

```
<%= f.submit "PUBLISH", :class => "greenbtn extrayo", :id => "publishbtn" %>


<script type="text/javascript">
  window.onbeforeunload = confirmExit;
  function confirmExit()
  {
    return "Ready to move on? Or you wanna leave?";
  }
  $( "#publishbtn" ).click(function() {
  $( "body" )
    .off( "click", "#publishbtn", confirmExit )
    .find( "#publishbtn" )
      .text( "Put into" );
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `window.onbeforeunload = null` to remove the listener. To remove it on form submit you could use something like this:

```
$('#someForm').on('submit', function (event) {
    window.onbeforeunload = null;
});
```

Where `someForm` is id of your `<form>` element.

Comment: Thank you so much! It worked like a charm! I'd upvote but I'm new to stackoverflow.

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow! You can mark this answer as accepted if it solves your problem. If you don't know how to that here is a nice post about accepting answers: http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235/238078

Comment: didn't work for me (don't know why (my answer did work (in Chrome)))

Answer (score 0):

I am doing this:

I add the class "confirm" to each field that should be confirmed if changed  like this:

```
<label id="first_label" for="FName">First Name:</label>
            <input id="first" class="confirm" type="text" name="FName" value="@FName" />
```

I set the value of needToConfirm when I submit the form like this:

```
<input id="save" type="submit" name="buttonSubmit" value="Save" onclick="needToConfirm = false" />
```

Then in my java script section I added this jQuery code:

```
    $(document).ready(function () {
        needToConfirm = false; });

     $(document).ready(function(){$(window).unload(function() 
       {
        if (needToConfirm) 
         {
            return confirm("Your unsaved data will be lost, continue?");
            return needToConfirm;
         }
       });
    });

    $(".confirm").change(function () {
        needToConfirm = true;
    });
```

Changing the value of a field with the confirm class will cause the warning to appear if the user attempts to leave the page without saving.  Otherwise it simply submits the form.

Answer (score 0):

You can set `window.onbeforeunload=null`.

You can do this a couple ways.  One way it to set the value after they submit the form as such (be sure to change the selector to target the right form):

```
$("#form").submit(function(){
    window.onbeforeunload=null
});
```

**Or** you can do this when the user clicks the submit button of the form.  Both approaches are correct.

```
$("#publishbtn").click(function() {
    window.onbeforeunload=null;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30061619/2135941) didn't work for me, this does work:
(Chrome)

html:

```
<input type="submit" onclick="clearConfirm();" value="Submit">
```

js:

```
function clearConfirm() {
    window.onbeforeunload = null;
}
```

Don't know why...